# Find an expression for the event that exactly two of the first four events occur.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A_1, A_2, · · · ,$ be a sequence of events of a sample space, not necessarily mutually exclusive.

$(a)$ Find an expression for the event that at most one of the first three events occurs.

Hint: the event that “at least one of the first two events occurs” is expressed as $A_1 ∪ A_2$.

$(b)$ Find an expression for the event that exactly two of the first four events occur.

My attempts:

$(a)$ "At most one of the first three events occurs" is equivalent to saying the complement of "at least two of the first three events occur".
And thus, this could be expressed as: $(A_1A_2∪A_2A_3∪A_3A_1)^c$, where $A_1A_2 = A_1 \cap A_2$ and so on.

$(b)$ I'm not sure about this part, but is "exactly two of the first four events occur" equivalent to saying the complement of ("at most one of the first four events occur intersection at least three of the first four events occur")?
And if so, how is it written as an expression?

Comment: Your answer to (a) seems fine.  As for (b), I would phrase it as "*At least two of the first four events occur but not at least three*" which yields using your notation $(A_1A_2\cup A_1A_3\cup \dots \cup A_3A_4)\setminus (A_1A_2A_3\cup A_1A_2A_4\cup \dots \cup A_2A_3A_4)$.  This does seem rather wordy though.  An alternate way of describing it is "*An even number of events from $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ occur different than $0$ and $4$*" which would yield something like $(\ominus_{n=1}^4 A_n)^c\setminus ((A_1A_2A_3A_4)\cup (A_1^cA_2^cA_3^cA_4^c))$

Comment: ... where $\ominus$ is the symmetric difference (*exclusive or*) which you can show that if applied successively results in $A_1\ominus A_2\ominus A_3\ominus \cdots \ominus A_n = \{x~:~x\text{ occurs in an odd number of }A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$